# what is the direct url of metacafe video to play in a div?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, flash

Can someone please help me by providing the "Direct Url" for playing metacafe videos in a div.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misinterpreting your question, the answer seems a bit too obvious, but anyways here it goes:

To embed for example this [video](http://www.metacafe.com/watch/5215722/deus_ex_human_revolution_story_trailer/) use:

```
<div style="background:#000000;width:440px;height:272px"><embed flashVars="playerVars=showStats=yes|autoPlay=no|videoTitle=Deus Ex: Human Revolution - Story Trailer" src="http://www.metacafe.com/fplayer/5215722/deus_ex_human_revolution_story_trailer.swf" width="440" height="272" wmode="transparent" allowFullScreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" name="Metacafe_5215722" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed></div>
```

Click the ' Embed' button below the video.

Of this code the Direct URL would be:

```
http://www.metacafe.com/fplayer/5215722/deus_ex_human_revolution_story_trailer.swf
```

Hope this helps